# Client and Server end (JavaScript and PHP validation)

Tags: javascript, php

How to put up client end validation just to check empty fields using JavaScript and to validate email , user name using PHP at server end. I am a beginner.

**So far i have done at Client end**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

       function checkme()
       {
           if(document.myform.uname.value == "")
           {
               alert("Please Enter your User Name")
               document.myform.uname.focus();
               return false;
           }

           if(document.myform.mail.value == "")
           {
               alert("Please Enter Your E-mail Address");
               document.myform.mail.focus();
               return false;
           }
return true;

}

    </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <form name="myform"  method="POST" action="index.php" onsubmit="return checkme();">


        User Name : <input type="text" name="uname" /><label> * </label>
        <br />

        E-Mail : <input type="text" name="mail" /><label> * </label>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" />


    </form>

</body>
```

**So far i have done at Server end**

```
    <?php

    $uname = $_POST["uname"];  $unameerr = $mailerr = "" ;
    $mail = $_POST["mail"] ;

    if (! isset($_POST['register']))
    {
        echo "You need to submit the form " ;
    }

    if (empty($_POST["uname"]) || empty($_POST["mail"]))
    {
        echo "All fields are required" ;
        exit ;
    }

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
     if(strlen($_POST["uname"])< 2 || (strlen($_POST["uname"])>12))

            {
                $unameerr = "Please Enter your USER NAME with in 2-12 characters" ;
            }
            else
            {
                $uname = $_POST["uname"] ;
            }

        if(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9_.]+\@+[A-Za-z]+\.+[a-z{2,4}]$/", $mail))

            {
                $mailerr = "Please Enter your email address in correct format[abc@abc.com]" ;
            }
            else
            {
                $mail = $_POST["mail"] ;
            }
    }    
    echo "Your inputs are :" ;

    echo "<br />" ;

    echo "Your User name is : " . $uname ;

    echo "<br />" ;

    echo "Your Registered E-mail is : " . $mail ;






    ?>

    <form>      <input type="button" value="Print A Copy" onsubmit="window.print()" /> </form>
```

Any Recommendations???

Comment: so... what's the problem with that? it works? any error? something?

Comment: Please let us know what difficulty you are facing in your code. explain us clearly what you need. that will help us to answer your question, and you're very welcome to StackOverflow btw :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't explain us what difficulty you are facing. i would recommend you to have a nice tutorial.

[Click Here for the PHP validation Tute](http://www.sitepoint.com/form-validation-with-php/)

[Click Here for the Javascript validation Tute](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_form_validations.htm)